# Oil in radiator but no water in oil

Tags: chevrolet, s10, oil-in-coolant

98 S10 4.3 I rebuilt top end of motor new head gaskets and all ,new radiator too . I put fresh oil in ran the motor for about ten min started tapping checked the oil and it was as low as the add mark  no oil in reservoir  but does blow out white smoke idk if it's because of the rebuild or condication need help .I also took apart the radiator to see the cooler in it and doesn't appear to have a hole so idk

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you have white smoke present, you've still got head gasket problems. Did you reuse the old head bolts? Most modern engines use torque to yield bolts which it's pretty much required to throw them away and get a new set when replacing a head gasket. Either that or are you sure you put the right head gaskets on it? Did you check the heads to ensure they are straight? What was the reason for rebuilding the top end in the first place?

Comment: It's not at all uncommon for oil to be forced into the cooling system when you have a problem with your head gasket, your cylinder head, or the engine block.  Regardless, you'll need to pull the head again and find out what's wrong.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 that looks like an Answer. Why don´t you post it as such?

Comment: @Daniel - Because it's a whole bunch of questions, not really an answer. The white smoke is only one part of the scenario here. I'd like to give a complete answer based on the whole picture. Besides, it really doesn't answer the question of why there's oil in the coolant.

Comment: Ok well I ran the truck today and it's taping hard like someone hitting metal together hard anyway I don't think it's the heads there new  gaskets and heads arnt cracked and torque to 75 ftlbs I think it's the oil pump but when it's running the motor acting like it has a big miss idk